# How to bring a wordpress widget into bootstrap?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, import

It's a fairly simple widget that goes into the header/Navbar. It was simply a display. And you could change the string through the backend of wordpress.

My question is how if possible do I salvage the code and use it on bootstrap3?
The code of the widget is in a .php and .css, And I need it on the right of my navbar header of my bootstrap site.

I clearly don't have enough experience to even know where to start, but if someone can point me in the right direction, it would be highly appreciated!

This is the code of the widget itself, which comes with a bunch of CSS.

```
/********************************************************/
/* FUNCTIONS
********************************************************/
function earthuru_money_widget()
{
    register_widget('EarthuruMoneyWidget');
}

class EarthuruMoneyWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    function EarthuruMoneyWidget()
    {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'EarthuruMoney', 'description' => __('Unity Pot', 'EarthuruMoney'));
        $control_ops = array('width' => 120, 'height' => 150, 'id_base' => 'earthuru_money');

        $this->WP_Widget('earthuru_money', __('Unity Pot', 'EarthuruMoney'), $widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }

    function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        extract($args);

        //Our variables from the widget settings.
        if (empty($instance['earthuru_money_euro']) || empty($instance['earthuru_money_usd'])) return;

        echo $before_widget . '<div id="earthuru_money"><div class="logo"><p>Unity Pot:</p></div><div class="values"><span class="currency euro">' . $instance['earthuru_money_euro'] . '</span><span class="euro">&euro;</span><span class="currency usd">' . $instance['earthuru_money_usd'] . '</span><span class="usd">&euro;</span> <span class="savings">Savings</span></div></div>' . $after_widget;
    }

    //Update the widget
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['earthuru_money_euro'] = strip_tags($new_instance['earthuru_money_euro']);
        $instance['earthuru_money_usd'] = strip_tags($new_instance['earthuru_money_usd']);

        return $instance;
    }

    function form($instance)
    {
        //Set up some default widget settings.
        $defaults = array('Key' => __('null', 'EarthuruMoney'));
        $instance = wp_parse_args((array)$instance, $defaults);
        ?>
        <p>
            <label
                for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('earthuru_money_euro'); ?>"><?php _e('Euro:', 'EarthuruMoney'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('earthuru_money_euro'); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('earthuru_money_euro'); ?>"
                   value="<?php echo $instance['earthuru_money_euro']; ?>" style="width:100%;"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label
                for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('earthuru_money_usd'); ?>"><?php _e('USD:', 'EarthuruMoney'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('earthuru_money_usd'); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('earthuru_money_usd'); ?>"
                   value="<?php echo $instance['earthuru_money_usd']; ?>" style="width:100%;"/>
        </p>
    <?php
    }
}

function earthuru_money_css()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('earthuru_money', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__));
}

// PLUGIN NOTIFICATION
add_action('widgets_init', 'earthuru_money_widget');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'earthuru_money_css');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid question.

Bootstrap is a responsive frontend framework.  You can build a theme using Bootstrap as the base framework.  However the question of how one would "salvage the code and use it on bootstrap3" doesn't make any sense.